# variable scope empty in html after edit in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

in controller I made a function that can change the content of my variable scope buut in my file html ( in div modal ) I cant get this new variable !!

```js
function myfunction(){
   $scope.details = ["a","b","c","d"];
   console.log($scope.details); 
   $("#myModal").modal();
}
```

```html
<body data-ng-controller="myAppCtrl" data-ng-app="myApp">      
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h2 class="modal-title" style="color:red;">{{details[0]}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Formateur: {{details[1]}} </h3>
          <p>Date de début: {{details[2]}} </p>
          <p>Date de fin: {{details[3]}} </p>
          <div ng-repeat="item in details[4]" ng-if="details.length > 3">
            <button style="float: left;" class="btn btn-default">{{ item }}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Quitter</button>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify the content of a modal?

Comment: yes it work....